# Sharepoint ?wsdl does not return WSDL file, returns the normal page instead

Tags: sharepoint, wsdl

Try this URL:

http://sharepoint.iceweb.com/sites/demo/default.aspx?wsdl

(user: demo@icemail.com, pass: demo)

As far as I remember this used to return the WSDL file for this, but it just returns the normal page instead.  How do I get the WSDL for a Sharepoint service?  I'm actually looking for the WSDL for the Sharepoint 2007 List service, so if anyone has a link for that, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your URL is a little wrong. Try this:

[`http://sharepoint.iceweb.com/sites/demo/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl`](http://sharepoint.iceweb.com/sites/demo/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl)

Answer (score 7):

You can only get WSDL from a webservice. You are trying to get a WSDL from a web page.
The URL corresponding to the list service is {weburl}/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

Here is a list af webservices available for SharePoint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390.aspx

Comment: And here is a list of application services, for example Excel Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559367.aspx