# How to download all the wsdl files from the sharepoint?

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint, wsdl

1. > I want to download the following wsdl files from

> sharepoint(Alerts.wsdl, dspsts.wsdl, lists.wsdl,
>   publishedlinksservice.wsdl, sites.wsdl, versions.wsdl ,admin.wsdl,
>   dws.wsdl, meetings.wsdl, permissions.wsdl, socialdataservice.wsdl,
>   views.wsdl ,authentication.wsdl, forms.wsdl, people.wsdl,
>   sharepointemailws.wsdl, spsearch.wsdl, webpartpages.wsdl ,copy.wsdl,
>   imaging.wsdl, search.wsdl, sitedata.wsdl, usergroup.wsdl, webs.wsdl).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486712/sharepoint-wsdl-does-not-return-wsdl-file-returns-the-normal-page-instead

Comment: Thoese links are not working properly and in that one is showing only some wsdl files not all of them @PatB

Comment: you need to change the server address to your server....

Answer (score 2):

Use the following URL's. Replace <server> with your server name. Also change the protocol `http` or `https`.

```
https://<server>/sites/_vti_adm/Admin.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Alerts.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/DspSts.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/DspSts.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Forms.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Imaging.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Meetings.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/people.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Permissions.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/publishedlinksservice.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/search.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Sites.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/socialdataservice.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/spsearch.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Versions.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Views.asmx?WSDL
https://<server>/sites/_vti_bin/Webs.asmx?WSDL
```

You can use `curl` to get them all very easily. Example:

```
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Admin.asmx?WSDL -o Admin.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Alerts.asmx?WSDL -o Alert.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx?WSDL -o authentication.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx?WSDL -o Copy.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/DspSts.asmx?WSDL -o DspSts.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/DspSts.asmx?WSDL -o DspSts.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx?WSDL -o Dws.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Forms.asmx?WSDL -o Forms.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Imaging.asmx?WSDL -o Imaging.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL -o Lists.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Meetings.asmx?WSDL -o Meetings.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/people.asmx?WSDL -o people.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Permissions.asmx?WSDL -o Permissions.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/publishedlinksservice.asmx?WSDL -o publishedlinksservice.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/search.asmx?WSDL -o search.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx?WSDL -o SiteData.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Sites.asmx?WSDL -o Sites.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/socialdataservice.asmx?WSDL -o socialdataservice.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/spsearch.asmx?WSDL -o spsearch.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?WSDL -o UserGroup.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Versions.asmx?WSDL -o Versions.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Views.asmx?WSDL -o Views.asmx.wsdl
curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://[sphost]/_vti_bin/Webs.asmx?WSDL -o Webs.asmx.wsdl
```